# Dynamic Array of Strings Causes Segfault

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault

I wrote some code to create a dynamic array of strings which is automatically resized once full.
Even though there seems to be no issue inserting elements in it, I get a segfault when trying to print all of the inserted values.

I have defined a starting size of 10 for the array, and I am assuming each string in the array will not be longer than 30 characters.

When main() is executed, the program should be allocating enough memory for 10 char pointers, and for each one of those pointers, enough memory to hold a string of 30 characters is allocated in the initialize_concordance() function.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_STRING_LENGTH 30
#define EXTENSION_STEP 10

int size = 0;
int max_size = 10;

void initialize_concordance(char **concordance) {

    for (int i = size; i < max_size; i++) {

        concordance[i] = malloc(MAX_STRING_LENGTH * sizeof(char));

    }

}

void push(char **concordance, char *word) {

    if (size >= max_size) {

        max_size += EXTENSION_STEP;
        realloc(concordance, max_size);
        initialize_concordance(concordance);

    }

    concordance[size] = word;
    size++;

}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    char **concordance = malloc(max_size * sizeof(char*));
    initialize_concordance(concordance);

    char *wordRead = "Hello";

    push(concordance, wordRead);
    push(concordance, wordRead);
    push(concordance, wordRead);
    push(concordance, wordRead);
    push(concordance, wordRead);
    push(concordance, wordRead);
    push(concordance, wordRead);
    push(concordance, wordRead);
    push(concordance, wordRead);
    push(concordance, wordRead);
    push(concordance, wordRead);
    push(concordance, wordRead);
    push(concordance, wordRead);
    push(concordance, wordRead);
    push(concordance, wordRead);
    push(concordance, wordRead);
    push(concordance, wordRead);

    printf("%s\n", concordance[0]);
    printf("%s\n", concordance[1]);
    printf("%s\n", concordance[2]);
    printf("%s\n", concordance[9]);
    printf("%s\n", concordance[10]);
    printf("%s\n", concordance[3]);
    printf("%s\n", concordance[4]);

}
```

Comment: Hint 1: Think about what [`realloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc) *returns*. Hint 2: How would you return value (like a new pointer) from a function?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude is correct, what he means is -->  update the pointer after realloc

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Shouldn't something like the following work? void *tmp = realloc(concordance, max_size); if (tmp != NULL) { concordance = tmp; }

Comment: @JoaquinPletcher That's a *start*. Now think about how you can return the new `concordancè` pointer.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to not storing the returned pointer from `realloc()`, the call to `realloc()` itself is not being passed correctly. You need to multiply by the size of a pointer, just as you did when you called `malloc()`.

Moreover, since `concordance` has to be modified before `push()` returns, you need to pass its pointer to `push()`.

```
void push(char ***concordance, char *word) {

    if (size >= max_size) {

        max_size += EXTENSION_STEP;
        void *tmp = realloc(*concordance, max_size * sizeof(char *));
        if (tmp == NULL) {
            /* ... handle failure */
            return;
        }
        *concordance = tmp;
        initialize_concordance(*concordance);

    }

    (*concordance)[size] = word;
    size++;

}
```

So, in `main()`, you will have to change how you call `push()`.

```
    push(&concordance, wordRead);
```

As a word of caution, you should check the result of each call to `malloc()` as well, and take appropriate action if it fails.